# Datatable row color based on Rest API results

Tags: rest, datatable

I have a Rest API call to pull data to create a Datatable.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to dynamically color the rows based on information in one of the columns (example here is if the registration date is over a year).  Seems pretty simple, if the registration date is over a year, row = red.  But being the noob I am I'm having trouble figuring out where to place the code.  Any help would be appreciated!  See code below.

```
function getRegistrations(){
var today = new Date();
var expiration = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 365));
var call = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('activeRegistrations')/items?$select=Title,Company,DeviceSN,RegistrationDate&$top=5000",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" }
    });

call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    var table = $('#currentRegistrations').DataTable();
    $('#currentRegistrations').on('click','tr',function(){
        var dataDst = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
    });

    $('#currentRegistrations').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        iDisplayLength: 5,
        aaData: data.d.results,
        select: true,
        aoColumns: [
            {mData: "Title"},
            {mData: "Company"},
            {mData: "DeviceSN"},
            {mData: "RegistrationDate"}
        ]
    });
});

call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving Tasks: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

Doing some searching I've found the below code snippet that should be the right idea, but I haven't figured out where this should be placed in my code :/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
        if ( data[4] >= "expiration" ){
            $(row).addClass('red');
        }
    }
})
```

});

Update:

I've played a little more with the coding and have gotten the callback to work, however I'm still stuck on the row actually changing color.  See below for updated code:

```
$('#currentRegistrations').DataTable({
destroy: true,
iDisplayLength: 5,
aaData: data.d.results,
select: true,
aoColumns: [
    {mData: "Title"},
    {mData: "Company"},
    {mData: "DeviceSN"},
    {mData: "RegistrationDate"}
],
rowCallback: function(row, data){
    if (data["Company"] == "company 1"){
        alert ("1");
        $(row).css("color","red");
    }
    else{
        alert ("2");
    }
}
```

});

This gives me the alerts where they should be, however does not change the row color or the color of the font, I've also tried ("background-color","red") with no luck.  It's got to be so close, any help is immensely appreciated

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27123409/how-to-apply-css-class-to-a-row-using-datatables-js

Comment: I've tried that one.  I think its different for this case because the data comes back in JSON format so all the responses are declared as "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of playing around, I was finally able to get this to work... I guess thanks for all the help?.. Just wanted to share this in case anyone else ever looked for something similar.

```
rowCallback: function(row, data){
if (data["RegistrationDate"] <= expiration.toISOString()){
    $('td:eq(6)', row).css('background-color', 'red');
}
else{
}
```